# Como validar dropdownlist que sean obligatorios en el backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy creando mi formulario en **ASP.NET MVC** con la ayuda de **C#** y requiero hacer unas validaciones de algunos dropdownlist que sean obligatorios tanto en el back y que no se permitan enviar hasta estar debidamente seleccionado

El siguiente es el formulario con los dropdownlist

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>
<div class="form-group" id="PriorityDiv">
                                        <label class="required-field" for="ticketPriorityInput">Prioridad:</label>
                                        <select class="form-control form-control-user " id="ticketPriorityInput" name="prioridad" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                                            <option>ALTO</option>
                                            <option>MEDIO</option>
                                            <option>BAJO</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group" id="ServiceDiv">
                                    <label class="required-field" for="ticketServiceInput">Servicio:</label>
                                    <select id="ticketServiceInput" name="service" onchange="loadSubService()" class="form-control form-control-user" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
                                        <option>Servicio 1</option>
                                        <option>Servicio 2</option>
                                        <option>Servicio 3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                                
                                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

El siguiente es el controlador de mi formulario

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateNewTicket()
            {
                var ticketPriorityInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"]);
                var ticketServiceInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketServiceInput"]);

            try
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {               
                    var ticket = new TK_HD_TICKETS
                    {
                        TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID = ticketPriorityInput,
                        TK_CT_SERVICES_ID = ticketServiceInput,

                        };
                        var result = ticketCreate.CreateNewTicket(ticket);

                        //Si no se guardo el ticket, se termina la transaccion y regresamos el mensaje de error
                        if (!result.Success)
                        return Json(new TicketResult
                        {
                            IsValid = false,
                            Error = "No se pudo crear el ticket, por favor inténtalo de nuevo."
                        });
                }
            }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                //Falló al tratar de registrar datos en la base de datos
                foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in e.ValidationErrors)
                    Console.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " +
                                      validationError.ErrorMessage);

                return Json(new TicketResult
                {
                    IsValid = false,
                    Error = "Ocurrió un error al crear el ticket, por favor inténtalo de nuevo."
                });
            }
            }
```

**Nota:** Dejo claro que el tipo de dato de `ticketPriorityInput` y `ticketServiceInput` es `int`

**Problema:**

Intente haciendo lo siguiente en el controlador

```
var ticketServiceInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketServiceInput"]);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticketServiceInput))
            {
                return Json(new TicketResult
                {
                    IsValid = false,
                    Error = "No se pudo crear el ticket, por favor seleccione un servicio."
                });
}
```

Pero me sale el error de que

> no se puede convertir de `int` a `string`

**Imagen error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que hacen las funciones JavaScript `onsubmit="validate_dropdown1()"` y `onchange="loadSubService()"`?. Y lo mas importante,  ¿cual es el problema?

Comment: Funcion `onsubmit="validate_dropdown1()"` no hace nada lo tengo que quitar y `onchange="loadSubService()"` permite carga los datos en otro dropdownlist que no nos interesa por el momento

Comment: De acuerdo, y que problema tienes en el back-end con la validación?. Es con `ticketPriorityInput` y `ticketServiceInput`?. Quieres comprobar que no sean null?

Comment: Revisa la pregunta nuevamente acabo de intentar algo y por eso me genera el error que menciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` es solo para comprobar valores de tipo **string**.

La comparación la debes hacer antes de convertir las variables a `Int32`, de la siguiente manera:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["ticketServiceInput"].ToString()))
        {
            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Error = "No se pudo crear el ticket, por favor seleccione un servicio."
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // Aquí conviertes a Int32 
            var ticketServiceInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketServiceInput"]);

           // Aquí sigue con tu código...
        }
```

**Nota**: También puedes hacer la comprobación `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, por si en el `<input/>` te introducen espacios en blanco.

Comment: Me dice que `TK_CT_SERVICES_ID` no existe en el contexto actual, recuerda que es un dropdownlist

Comment: Claro que si!. Te he respondido a la pregunta con un ejemplo (no lo copies y pegues), TK_CT_SERVICES_ID es una variable de tu código (tú sabrás que para que sirve). Adapta la respuesta a tu código amigo...;), y si te ha ayudado en algo a solucionar tu problema, **valórala**.

Comment: Revisa la pregunta acabo de colocar una imagen con el error

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata de un proyecto `asp.net mvc` cuentas con `Data Annotations` para implementar validaciones sobre el model que envias al controller

[Parte 6: Usar anotaciones de datos para la validación del modelo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

[Validación del modelo en Asp.net MVC (Data Annotations)](https://www.tiracodigo.com/index.php/programacion/mvc/validacion-del-modelo-en-asp-net-mvc-data-annotations)

No se usa ningun `Request.Form` se usa `Data Binding`

En la carpeta `Model` creas la clase

```
public class TicketModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? ticketPriorityInput {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public int? ticketServiceInput {get;set;}
}
```

Para despues usar esta en el action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateNewTicket(TicketModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid){
      //codigo
      return View();
   }

     //codigo
}
```

Comment: Ya había consultado lo de los Data Annotations pero no lo estoy implementando por el momento, gracias igual por tu respuesta

Comment: pero es que deberia implementarlo, generar un model tampoco es tan complicado, porque solucionar un parche que estas queriendo hacer si puede hacerlo bien desde el principio